# How to extract texture from vtk for use in blender?

Tags: textures, blender, mesh, vtk, itk

I have a mesh and texture information in a .vtk file. What would be the best way to import both(mesh info+ texture info) into a blender?

Currently, I am able to extract the mesh information only using slicer by exporting to .obj file but I do not know to export the texture info.

Answer (score 0):

[ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/) should be better than Slicer for converting `.vtk` into other formats.

Comment: It would be really helpful if could tell me which format would be the best for my application.

Comment: I have never really used Blender. But try Wavefront `.OBJ` format. Based on https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25962 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65918/how-do-i-add-a-texture-when-importing-from-obj-scan